# Custom UITextField blurred text

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitextfield

When a UITextField with custom frame (200 × 54 px) loses focus, the text looks blurred.

[image: example screenshot]
<sub>(source: [idzr.org](http://idzr.org/iu59))</sub>

Is this a common problem? Is there any workaround / solution known?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a number of references to this bug through Google, but everybody worked around it by playing with font sizes. After much hunting I found [this thread](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1216-fuzzy-graphics-when-cgrect-given-float-value.html) that says anti-aliasing is applied when a view's frame contains fractional pixel values, e.g. if you calculate its size as a fraction of the super view.

Sure enough, casting the `CGRect` values to `int` for the view's frame worked perfectly. So as an example, if you wanted your text field to be centered vertically in the superview, you should use an `int` cast like this:

```
textFieldWidth = 300;
textFieldHeight = 31;
offsetX = 0;
offsetY = (superview.bounds.size.height - textFieldHeight) / 2;

textField.frame = CGRectMake((int) offsetX,
                             (int) offsetY,
                             (int) textFieldWidth,
                             (int) textFieldHeight);
```

There is also the `CGRectIntegral` function that you can use to convert a `CGRect` to integral values.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this seems to be the best solution.

Comment: I've seen this happen in Interface Builder as well.  I made sure to check the sizes to make sure they did not contain fractions.  My solution was to recreate the button, which is lame.  But it's easy to do, just click the button, hold down the option key, then drag it over.  This will create a new button identical to the last one, but with proper anti-aliasing.  All that's left to do after that is hookup your actions and outlets and re-position it.  Oh, and delete the old button. :)